# POST form with action="#" using httr

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

I'm trying to post a form using httr. I thought an action tag specifies where the form is being submitted to.

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Using the POST method in the httr library, I usually use the action tag as part of the URL but I'm unsure what to use if I come across the above.

Comment: that `<form>` `POST` is most likely being handled in-page (prbly by javascript). If not, then it's being sent to the same URL the page is at. you're better off looking at the Developer Tools "Network" view to see what's really going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I've noticed there is a POST request which doesn't have a response (Status 303). This is then followed by a GET request.

One thing I have noticed is that the Set-Cookie is the same in each of the network activity headers. Do I need to extract the cookie from the POST and use it to GET the response?

Sorry if I've gotten this completely wrong, I'm still a newbie to web scraping.

Comment: you may need to. take a look at the `curlconverter` pkg to help with this and also right-click list entries in Developer Tools and feed the Copy as cURL to `curlconverter::straighten()`

Comment: I managed get the POST request to return a status 303 by using the `httr::cookies` and editing the request header to match what was coming through in the Developer Tools "Network" view.

Just wanted to say thank you for pointing me in the right direction!